# Python Generate unique ranges of a specific length and categorize them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe column which specifies how many times a user has performed an activity. 
eg.

```
>>> df['ActivityCount']
Users     ActivityCount
User0     220
User1     190
User2     105
User3     109
User4     271
User5     265
     ...
User95     64
User96     15
User97    168
User98    251
User99    278
Name: ActivityCount, Length: 100, dtype: int32


>>> activities = sorted(df['ActivityCount'].unique())
[9, 15, 16, 17, 20, 23, 25, 26, 28, 31, 33, 34, 36, 38, 39, 43, 49, 57, 59, 64, 65, 71, 76, 77, 78,
83, 88, 94, 95, 100, 105, 109, 110, 111, 115, 116, 117, 120, 132, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 144, 145, 148, 153, 155, 157, 162, 168, 177, 180, 182, 186, 190, 192, 194, 197, 203, 212, 213, 220, 223, 231, 232, 238, 240, 244, 247, 251, 255, 258, 260, 265, 268, 269, 271, 272, 276, 278, 282, 283, 285, 290]
```

According to their ActivityCount, I have to divide users into 5 different categories eg `A, B, C, D` and `E`. 
Activity Count range varies from time to time. In the above example it's approx in-between `(9-290)` (lowest and highest of the series), it could be `(5-500)` or  `(5 to 30)`. 
In above example, I can take the max number of activities and divide it by 5 and categorize each user between the range of  58 `(from 290/5)` like `Range A: 0-58`, `Range B: 59-116`, `Range C: 117-174`...etc

Is there any other way to achieve this using pandas or numpy, so that I can directly categorize the column in the given categories?
Expected output: -

```
>>> df
Users     ActivityCount  Category/Range 
User0     220             D
User1     190             D
User2     105             B 
User3     109             B
User4     271             E  
User5     265             E
     ...
User95     64             B
User96     15             A
User97    168             C
User98    251             E
User99    278             E
```

Comment: What are the criteria for creating these buckets? Do you want them to be equal in size? Or do you want the members of each bucket to be similar to each other?

Comment: @Roy2012 - equal in size. Thanks

Comment: @Roy2012 - Just a curiosity, how can we do this for `members of each bucket to be similar to each other`.

Comment: Making the items in each bucket similar to each other is known as a clustering / classification problem. It's a well known field of machine learning. Specifically, there's an algorithm called k-means that attempts to do just that.

Comment: Hi @Roy2012 - Thanks, This works perfectly to me. Could you please add your k-means approach in the answer, I'm keen to know how it would result, I feel that approach would be more appropriate solution to me. (my actual problem statement is a bit different, not explained here due to data privacy protection)

Comment: Done. to be honest, it's a kind of an overkill in this case - but it's still a cool algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural way to do that would be to split the data into 5 quanties, and then split the data into bins based on these quantities. Luckily, pandas allows you do easily do that:

```
df["category"] = pd.cut(df.Activity, 5, labels= ["a","b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

The output is something like:

```
    Activity Category
34       115        b
15        43        a
57       192        d
78       271        e
26        88        b
6         25        a
55       186        d
63       220        d
1         15        a
76       268        e
```

### An alternative view - clustering

In the above method, we've split the data into 5 bins, where the sizes of the different bins are equal. An alternative, more sophisticated approach, would be to split the data into 5 clusters and aim to have the data points in each cluster as similar to each other as possible. In machine learning, this is known as a clustering / classification problem.

One classic clustering algorithm is [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). It's typically used for data with multiple dimensions (e.g. monthly activity, age, gender, etc.) This is, therefore, a very simplistic case of clustering.

In this case, k-means clustering can be done in the following way:

```
import scipy
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq, kmeans, whiten

df = pd.DataFrame({"Activity": l})

features = np.array([[x] for x in df.Activity])
whitened = whiten(features)
codebook, distortion = kmeans(whitened, 5) 
code, dist = vq(whitened, codebook)

df["Category"] = code
```

And the output looks like:

```
    Activity  Category
40       138         1
79       272         0
72       255         0
13        38         3
41       139         1
65       231         0
26        88         2
59       197         4
76       268         0
45       145         1
```

A couple of notes:

- The labels of the categories are random. In this case label '2' refers to higher activity than lavel '1'.
- I didn't migrate the labels from 0-4 to A-E. This can easily be done using pandas' `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution:

```
df['Categ'] = pd.cut(df.ActivityCount, bins=5, labels=list('ABCDE'))
```

It creates *Categ* column - a result of division of *ActivityCount*
into 5 bins, labelled with *A*, ... *E*.

Borders of bins are set by division of full range into *n* subranges of
equal size.

You can also see the borders of each bin, calling:

```
pd.cut(df.ActivityCount, bins=5, labels=list('ABCDE'), retbins=True)[1]
```