# Binning of continuous variable into given number of classes

Tags: python, dataframe, binning

I have y_train label data in range (0-1) float numbers. The task is to make 4 classes from it.

[y_train label score distribution looks like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UDKr.png). Do you know statistical approaches how I can binarize it?, not by equal bin intervals.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017979/python-generate-unique-ranges-of-a-specific-length-and-categorize-them/62018352#62018352 (and the accepted answer). Does it help?

Comment: @martineau Thank you, I will try to apply k-means on 'score'

Comment: Olzhas: Wasn't me, it was @Roy2012.